Use YAML-Templates to Create AAP Credentials
To create the credentials in the awx we would like to use the awx.awx collection.
We process a yaml file that is read in as a template and rendered with jinja2.
The yaml code should then be read into the playbook using set_facts.
We have YAML code in a j2 file and we would like to use it in a playbook by ansible.builtin.set_fact.
Here the j2-yml-File: vars/Credentials.yml.j2:
{% filter from_yaml %}
################################################################
# credential_type: Source Control
################################################################
vars_credentials:
  all:
  - name: 'CRED_GIT_myuser'
    description: 'Git-User myuser at Git-Projekt'
    credential_type: Source Control
    organization: myorg
    state: 'present'
    inputs:
      ssh_key_data: '{{ lookup("file", "ssh/id_rsa_myuser") }}'
      ssh_key_unlock: 'AxxxxxxZ'
################################################################
{% endfilter %}

In the Playbook:
- name: "read vars/Credentials.yml.j2 as template"
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    Q: "{{ lookup('template', 'vars/Credentials.yml.j2') }}"

- name: "Show all from vars_credentials at vars/Credentials.yml.j2"
  debug:
    msg: "{{ q }}"
  loop:  "{{ Q.vars_credentials.all | list }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: q

Unfortunately, the private key is modified quite strangely by jinja2 in this process, so that it is not usable.
Output from debug:
  9│res:
 10│  changed: false
 11│  msg: All items completed
 12│  results:
 13│  - _ansible_item_label:
 14│      credential_type: Source Control
 16│      inputs:
 17│        ssh_key_data: '-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY----- b3BlbnNzaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxyeXB0AAAAGAAAABBBAIRG5X
 18│          j8cgfTvYng0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDDy4V/plIV MdHT/z2y1q3jZufbItSaidxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxMBARgliFHUAtcAj1o803aR/
 19│          +uuhIFkmoWlA9xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxCYZU5w5SOHivms52LsY3SSwNI MkrETTmdy6XAZQ4FR/Wv6cxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxfL7QrIR+GYGwFEvCIBsM4F+fQcq
 20│          hL9JAnxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxpWPDJWVggKAOwhngeQsNO3YwmSc2z5U//q pv7s6LdpSbywwd3oYfxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxipvv6RAAADwP8dgtVN9CIO0g
 21│          NXVbZpmEFxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxfeuGdLbMLOY3Xfl250GvmEnIlXDxUG8uHeJA5 URIwWauCHwtFQNnRSJcuupn5/Ft9+pGxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxmgUy91sVSyLOnBuzunY4kzL
 22│          9RZ1SwJ3CEcxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxqlEc1csJbtt5qzlO7eUS+DWigs9 k5O9SfkIVk1KDNRITXzD/Cnk3Z6c9e4mxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxAItT1dKi3tXHfZiQKE
 23│          yqzZnEXU3JpN6xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxPLzIyKl2QcNgdcn0drbxlNYJ/3hTnHjZf2c 9ltngGogUC85tvQsUxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxDEDLxPR/N2el7qbNIuoEV
 24│          +VisxQ5G+QGJTH0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx5TYE2DmMTj9YGQ/HYUWizAdq30lZH3qL L/gKPKqKK7Pxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx5iiL9OnlWxEoiO4w
 25│          kJZ7ls9Vfxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxp5GPp+55SozE/ohoQBPMtNLq u+gUKTmG1ncGWL+RiGFXr5vQFsnMvD+xnT/0sIvrtC39a9pgdoPTh4/YXK4gpp1ObCzior
 26│          RSBInYjnIsCDRJ5ZJ6rTmKzPIns19qZFuiPmwGBUcytPiwyTyS3axhoCwzS4bIKbMQEI3j TtBb/1ft5Nn7KwaX969FCFDSBYaf6jc0nBdQywj+mVCUdM/CsVTpqjjAD1afmhNGcUMDna
 27│          wPZL3Lu6WIL3lUPCMwVYOUVIyvci3SZz4bo478xmBlKf/lWPndno9XmblIjvtwXU6+X0fq N3864XSmnx33E6HOaqCs0+Z34dLzFFevc9jntVGXVGC6QB4ubPDscBvLNGK8bbzVrKo0go
 28│          +QhNfvfPEIagzFD2YEqn0RNwCQDPBVhHi9h1zl0eoKjvEtpUVlFItBHQdG82kYErgeNZPr kxh66UXsumzpwFs3TMsNZS1hFQCeHmn3FnbD8TmhldJnRCuBZMsTwiMcddaFv+ycZcneMx
 29│          ZRQH3V+Ovf2MJFN+TE7rMfnPSNp/Dw4qEQTCjIr9AVDbfThJ1Asf96PqplalkOFPaYbIGc LJVRaTo1BJ5JQ4tVYgN0E0pBl9SwP8vGCzdyJ8uizfbOl8PiCRSm6oUcH6AmVT7eOMk3VT
 30│          koM6Dw9Q== -----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----'
 31│        ssh_key_unlock: AxxxxxxZ

How can I prevent jinja2 from destroying the key?

Why are you trying to template a YAML file containing a lookup instead of loading the same file as vars and calling the awx.awx.credentials module directly?

Maybe I didn't understand your original intention but I assume that you actually wanted to load the list of credentials and iterate over it like this using awx.awx.credential module:
# vars/credentials.yml
---
vars_credentials:
  all:
  - name: 'CRED_GIT_myuser'
    description: 'Git-User myuser at Git-Projekt'
    credential_type: Source Control
    organization: myorg
    state: 'present'
    inputs:
      ssh_key_data: '{{ lookup("file", "ssh/id_rsa_myuser") }}'
      ssh_key_unlock: 'AxxxxxxZ'

# playbook.yaml
---
- name: Create the credentials
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars_files:
    - vars/credentials.yml
  tasks:    
    - name: Create a valid SCM credential from a private_key file
      credential:
        name: "{{ item.name }}"
        description: "{{ item.description }}"
        organization: "{{ item.organization }}"
        state: "{{ item.state }}"
        credential_type: "{{ item.credential_type }}"
        inputs:
          ssh_key_data: "{{ item.ssh_key_data }}"
          ssh_key_unlock: "{{ item.ssh_key_unlock }}"
      loop: "{{ vars_credentials.all }}"


Hello Alexander
This is exactly the procedure we originally had.
However, due to the large number of AAP clusters, we have the problem that the vars files become very large and recurring YAML patterns arise, which we would like to generate using templates.
So the jinja2 template should be loaded via a lookup filter and superimposed on the setfacts.
Unfortunately, it seems that the newlines (/n) of the private key are replaced by blanc (" ") characters and therefore no longer work.
